'npm run dev' in astrojs fails: "Unexpected token import"
I'm trying to get astro to run.
I've installed a project using 'npm create astro@latest'.
I've accepted all the project defaults.
If I then descend into the directory of the new projects and do 'npm run dev', I get the following:
/home/bob/play/astroplay/mechanical-mars/node_modules/astro/astro.js:23
        const semver = await import('semver');
                             ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mechanical-mars@0.0.1 dev: `astro dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mechanical-mars@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bob/.npm/_logs/2024-04-07T04_34_53_415Z-debug.log


What version of node are you using (can run node --version on command line to get this)
